# Pivoting data but keeping it aligned in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a big dataframe in R that looks like the following:

```
Age   Gene1   Gene2   Gene3 
33     0       1       1
57     1       0       1
90     1       1       1
```

I'm trying to plot this data in a bar graph, with the frequency that the genes are plotted against the age. When I try to pivot the data using:

```
pivoted_df <- df %>%
pivot_longer(AGE, names_to="genes", values_to="count")
```

This does pivot the data but my resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
Age  Gene  Count
33   Gene1   0
33   Gene2   1
33   Gene3   1  
57   Gene1   1
57   Gene2   0
57   Gene3   1
90   Gene1   1
90   Gene2   1
90   Gene3   1
```

Is there a way for me to pivot the data without repeating the ages? I.E still keep the genes and the count columns, but assign multiple values from that to one age?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "without repeating the ages" or "assign multiple values from that one age". Could you please show your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this where you reshape your data from wide to long using `melt` and create the "Age" `as.factor` to plot stacked bars like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Age   Gene1   Gene2   Gene3 
33     0       1       1
57     1       0       1
90     1       1       1", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
df %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Age") %>%
  mutate(Age = as.factor(Age)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(fill = "gene", y = "count") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! With that, the ages arent in order, they've managed to jumble themselves up (the whole dataframe is about 300 lines). Do you know of a way to fix this?

Comment: The 'reshape' package is obsolete and has been replaced by 'tidyr', and you absolutely don't need to use it here (in fact, the result of your `melt()` call is identical to that of the `pivot_longer()` call in the question).